# Groovy (Jenkins) How to Import / Read File into ${WORKSPACE}

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Need your kind advise on this.  I am very new to Jenkins pipeline and groovy.  I have also Googled quite a bit about this specific thing but can't find any definite answers (mostly due to how inexperience I am so I might be missing it).

I have a groovy that is used to run a Jenkins job, at one point I have to run a python script in $WORKSPACE (see below)

```
        stage("Compile Canary") {
        steps {
            script {
                  Map bbMap = [
                    name: env.STAGE_NAME,
                    commitID: gitInfo.GIT_COMMIT,
                    url: env.BUILD_URL,
                    message: "Local Compile"
                  ]
                try {
                    updateBitBucket.inProgress(bbMap)
                    sh label: '', script: '''
                        #!/bin/bash
                        set -e
                        cd $WORKSPACE/automation/
                        pip install --upgrade pip
                        pip install botocore==1.19.50
                        pip install boto3==1.16.0
                        python bin/install-dependencies.py
```

**All the pip install / upgrade and boto installs went fine**, it's only when running this section:

> python bin/install-dependencies.py

that is having issues due to the fact that it cannot find the file (see below for Jenkins output)

```
+ python bin/install-lambda-dependencies.py
python: can't open file 'bin/install-dependencies.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The error is obvious, which begs the question, how can I import this file?  Can I copy it to the git repo and then import it?  I'm using this python script because there are quite a long list of dependencies, and also I want to use this script as a standard across my team.

FYI: **the python file is currently residing in the same code repository as the groovy file**, it is placed in "bin" directory.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `how can I import this file?` - it depends on where it is located...

Comment: What I noticed here at the first glance, you use `$WORKSPACE` which is a variable available Jenkins pointing at the workspace where Jenkins runs the job. However the variable is not expanded because you do not use """ but ''' for the script. This means it will be expanded by the shell so it must be available in the shell, if not you get an empty string and the `cd` command does not what you expect. Please check this again or just put a `pwd` before python command.

Comment: @daggett Currently the file is in the (bin folder) inside code repository with the groovy file.

Comment: @Catalin the $WORKSPACE is not giving any problems, I did tried your suggestion and change the script to use """ however when CDing into the workstation's directory, it was "not found" and thus pip installs won't even start, unlike previously when using ''' it will install. Note that this groovy was copied from another jenkins job and that job's build was working. Must be missing something.

Comment: @Catalin I tried your suggestion of putting pwd in front of the python command, and I think it just printed the full path (in the Jenkins console output) but not doing anything else.  I don't think the .py script runs.

Comment: `pwd` was just to verify your current directory. if `cd` works correctly then you should be in a folder containing `bin/install-lambda-dependencies.py`.